# How to get current directive and it's host element instead of getting from all directive instance

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a tool tip directive. when i click on any of the element where tooltip directive added it shows the tooltip. works fine.

in case of user press on escape button I would like to close the tooltip. the tooltip directive implemented in a single page with multiple instance. once the tooltip closed, I would like to `focus` back to the parent. ( host listener ). for the I try with following code. ( snippet )

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  public escape($event) {
    if ($event.target && $event.key.toLowerCase() === 'escape') {
      console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement;); //consoles all instance.
      this.hostElement.focus();
      this.removeComponent();
    }
  }
```

the problem is, I am not able to get the target one at present where i open from. Instead I am consoled in `$event.target` of all directive. for me consoles more that 20 buttons. including the one i finally clicked. so how to handle this scenario? how can i focus back to the `hostlistner` where I was in?
how to get only the last directive properties alone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: You will probably have some indication in the directive/component that it is currently open. So I would just check ```if(this.isOpen) { // remove it }```

Comment: @LukaszGawrys - can you show me an sample or demo. do you want to add boolean where and how?

Comment: It might be a boolean property - how do you show the tooltip? On click or on hover? It might be set right there as true and reseted in your ```removeComponent``` method.